# Binding to Color property of Item in ListView doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have this code. Each item in ListView includes Label and CheckBox elements. Label represents the title of binded Lineseries item, Checkbox binded to IsVisible property of LineSeries item.

I want that trigger will set  the Background property (of Border element in Checkbox ControlTemplate) to color of the LineSeries element, when LineSeries element is visible. Setting to LightGray color works, also changing IsVisible property works, but background of Border do not change.

```
  <ListView Name="MyListView"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="253" Margin="445,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Series}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="2" Background="{Binding Color}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <CheckBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                            <Border Width="15" Height="15" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" />
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource OxycolorToColorConverter}}"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </CheckBox.Style>
                    </CheckBox>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Title}" Padding="1" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(OxyColor), typeof(Brush))]
class OxycolorToColor: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ox = (OxyColor) value;
        var color = Color.FromArgb(ox.A, ox.R, ox.G, ox.B);
        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return OxyColors.Purple;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a ControlTemplate but inside it you don't use the Background property so it's never shown.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Border Width="15" 
            Height="15" 
            BorderBrush="Gray" 
            BorderThickness="2" 
            CornerRadius="3"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource OxycolorToColorConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov use a Style and set the Command property to a binding